# incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: node.js, express

On POSTing data to my expressjs app, this is what I am getting:

```
node(58287,0x7fff771ad960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff8a8600c58: incorrect
    checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Any idea why?

**Update:**

Here is some code:

**Client side:**

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'user/' + id,
 type: 'POST',
 dataType:'JSON',
 data: JSON.stringify(data),
 success: function(response){
  console.log(response);
 }      
});
```

**Server side:**

```
app.post('/user/:id', function(req,res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(data);
});
```

When I **use JSON.stringify** on the client side, I am hitting this weird error:

> node(58461,0x7fff771ad960) malloc: *** error for object
>   0x7fa861d00e28: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was
>   probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6

When I **don't use JSON.stringify** on the client side, I get **'null' strings** on the server side.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Node are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced this same error recently. Here's the fix:

Node.js has had some bugs that cause it to install improperly from source under OS X (see e.g. [issue 2061](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2061)). The good news is that **the packaged installer installs it correctly.** So, simply uninstall Node, then head to http://nodejs.org/#download and run the Macintosh Installer.

I've reported this bug on the Node issue tracker [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3165).

Answer (score 2):

This is liable to be a bug in `nodejs`'s internals. (Or, if expressjs has any native-code bindings, perhaps expressjs.)

There's no easy way for you to write this kind of bug yourself in JavaScript. If you can reproduce this at will, they'd probably like a bug report. Try to figure out the least amount of code that can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error today, and updating Node.js through MacPorts from 0.8.9_0 to 0.8.10_1 fixed the issue.
It doesn't seem this was specifically adressed though, as bug reports and the changelog don't indicate that (http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/09/25/node-v0-8-10-stable/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into the *cause* of these issues (plural - there are clearly at least two bugs somewhere along the line - jquery, node, express), although a summary and workaround are as follows:

When your client side code looks like in your updated question the server obviously shouldn't crash with a malloc error (bug #1), although it is understandable that the query is mistreated, since you're telling jquery to send json and then you send a string.

bug #2 is simply `null --> "null"` along the pipe. This at least doesn't cause a server crash, because data types match headers (i.e. everyone think we're using json), however someone is converting nulls to strings. My baseless suspicion is that it's express/connect.

Finally, the workaround is simply to wrap your data in a way that manages to be transported, and then unwrap on the server side:

**Client side:**

```
$.post({
   url: 'user/' + id,
   data: {workaround: JSON.stringify(data)}, // no null strings this way
   success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
   }      
});
```

**Server side:**

```
app.post('/user/:id', function(req,res){
   var id = req.params.id;
   var data = JSON.parse(req.body.workaround); // unwrap
   console.log(data);
});
```

If I find time, I'll investigate and try and post a bug report somewhere (it's a problem when you don't know whose fault this is...), please try do this as well.

Comment: I posted this issue on the expressjs google groups as well but I haven't received any response there yet.

Comment: Also, The query is not wrong in the client side code that I posted. 'dataType': 'json' is the format of the response that you expect from the server, not the data type that you send to it.

Comment: @Rajat, indeed, that `dataType` always trips me up, I proxy it to be renamed `returnDataType`... The workaround still works though, and is pretty simple to implement in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You are are calling console.log server-side on 'data' which is not defined in the scope of your example.